# Exoplayer Orientation problem when rotate to Landscape

Tags: android, orientation, exoplayer, landscape-portrait, savestate

When the video plays in Exoplayer its fine but when it rotates the video starts again.
I want to make sure that the when the video rotates the video resumes to same position
I have saved the playersCurrent position but still its not working.
Please help.....

```
public class RecipeStepDescriptionFragment extends Fragment {


    @BindView(R.id.playerView)
    PlayerView playerView;

    @BindView(R.id.stepDescription)
    TextView stepDescription;

    @BindView(R.id.ingredientsCardSteps)
    CardView ingredientsCardSteps;

    @BindView(R.id.ingredientsListStepDescription)
    TextView ingredientsListStepDescription;


    @BindView(R.id.widgetButtonStepDescription)
    FloatingActionButton widgetButton;


    private SimpleExoPlayer player;

    private static final String TAG = "StepDetail";


    String videoUrl;
    String longDescription;
    boolean tablet;
    String ingredients;
    String name;

    public RecipeStepDescriptionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_step_description, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);





        if (getArguments() != null) {
            videoUrl = getArguments().getString("videoURL");
            longDescription = getArguments().getString("description");
            tablet = getArguments().getBoolean("tablet");
            ingredients = getArguments().getString("ingredients");
            name = getArguments().getString("name");
        //recipeList = (List<Steps>) getArguments().getSerializable("recipe_steps");*/
        }
        stepDescription.setText(longDescription);
        if (!tablet) {
            ingredientsCardSteps.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            ingredientsListStepDescription.setText(ingredients);
        }
        if (videoUrl != null) {
            playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (videoUrl.equals("")) {
                playerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), new DefaultTrackSelector());
                playerView.setPlayer(player);
                DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "exo-demo"));
                ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
                player.prepare(mediaSource);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

            }


        } else {
            playerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null && player != null) {
            player.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getLong("current_position"));
     player.setPlayWhenReady(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("play_state"));
        }



        widgetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("INGREDIENTS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("ingredients", ingredients);
                editor.putString("name", name);
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Widget Added to Home Screen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return rootView;
    }


    public void initializePlayer(){
        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getContext(), new DefaultTrackSelector());
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getContext(), Util.getUserAgent(getContext(), "exo-demo"));
        ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if ((Util.SDK_INT > 23)) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (player != null) {
            outState.putLong("current_position", player.getCurrentPosition());
            outState.putBoolean("play_state", player.getPlayWhenReady());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop:called ");
        playerView.setPlayer(null);
        if (player != null)
           player.release();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy:called ");
        playerView.setPlayer(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if ((Util.SDK_INT <= 23 || player == null)) {
            initializePlayer();
        }

    }


}
```

This is the link to the repository..
https://github.com/Rahulxx01/Baking-App-Nanodegree

Comment: What kind of testing have you done? Do you know for a fact that having your code segment that puts it back where it was is supposed to go in the onCreateView method?

Comment: I am trying to use Expresso for Manual Testing .
I didnt get your other question. @Kwright02

Comment: The android life cycle is complicated. Are you 100% sure that whenever the screen is rotated it calls onCreateView again?

Comment: Yes it calls again since the video is getting restarted from beginning @Kwright02

Comment: Ok so then the next think to make sure of is that the video position is actually being saved. A good approach is maybe after it rotates the screen make it toast the value of the variable that's holding the video time position to make sure that's correct. If that's correct then there's a few other things to think about but let's try that first.

Comment: @Kwright02 I added a toast message in the onCreateView method to check if the position is being saved 
At first when the activity starts the value of postion is null
When I rotate the value of position is still null
Its not saving the postion.

Comment: So we found where the issue is, now let's think about how we can solve it. Do we want to temporarily store that position in sharedPreferences or to a local file?

Comment: If you check my code I have used this

`@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (player != null) {
        outState.putLong("current_position", player.getCurrentPosition());
        outState.putBoolean("play_state", player.getPlayWhenReady());
    }
}`

to save the current postion but i guess its not working.

Comment: I saw that, but is that method actually being called when you need it to? If not I'd consider one of the options I mentioned above.

Comment: @Kwright02 I got the problem 
The position is being saved when I rotate the device I get the new position in the form of Toast but then the I get another toast with position value as Null.

Comment: @Kwright02 onCreateView is called twice I feel

Comment: That seems to be a possibility or rather that onSavedInstanceState is being called twice.

Answer (score 5):

try adding this line to your player Activity declaration in manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
```

Comment: Not working my application is getting hanged when i use this . Please help me on this